# Proper Use of GAE ndb.ComputedProperty

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I have a class of videos in my GAE project and I want to be able to search by their score which is the upvotes subtracting the downvotes.  I want to be able to query this value and I want to get it in the most efficient manner.  I believe that getting is with a computed property is the best way in the following manner:

```
class Video(ndb.Model):
    title = ndb.StringProperty(required = True)
    description = ndb.TextProperty()

    upvotes = ndb.IntegerProperty(required = True)
    downvotes = ndb.IntegerProperty(required = True)
    score = ndb.ComputedProperty(lambda self: self.upvotes - self.downvotes)
```

I was curious though if the ComputedProperty has any performance drags?  Would it be more efficient to just add to or subtract from the score value each time that an upvote or downvote is given?

Comment: it isn't `lambda self` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simple computations (like the one in your example) there shouldn't be much of a performance drag. Yes, the calculation is run whenever you read the data, but there's far more logic involved in constructing the result set in the first place; a single subtraction isn't going to affect anything.

For more complex calculations, yes, there could be a performance hit.

Comment: Okay great, thanks, this is a much cleaner solution for me so I was hoping it was fine.

Comment: Just a small correction: the computed property is only run on write, not read. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#computed

Comment: @RobCurtis that's incorrect. *"the stored value is ignored when the entity is read back from the Datastore; rather, the value is recomputed by calling the function whenever the value is requested"*

Comment: @Amber, ah I see, I had paid too much attention to the _Caution: ComputedProperties are not calculated on query, but rather on put()_ but I see now there is more to it. Thanks for the correction!